# Calling $this->lang->line with a variable as parameter (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

My problem is quite straightforward but I just can't figure out a solution.

I want to call `$this->lang->line()` but with a variable as parameter.

For example:

```
$country = 'Italy';
$this->lang->line($country);
```

should return what `$this->lang->line('Italy')` would return.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that you are in a controller, or in a view populated by a controller that has the language library loaded. Are you getting an error? Is there anything being outputted? Are you trying to set the website language to Italian? Because that's not what your code is doing. It's just fetching the string equivalent of 'Italy' from the currently loaded language file.

Comment: Thx for the answer. The code is in the controller and has the language file loaded. If I try without the variable ($this->lang->line('Italy')) it works just fine. But when I try to change it with the variable $country there is no output.

Comment: Are you sure you're echoing the result in both cases? Are you sure the variable is identical to 'Italy'? Remember that PHP array keys are case sensitive.

Comment: oh my, you put me to shame here, it was a case sensitivity issue after all... Thank you very much anyway :)

Comment: Hehe, that always happens to me too! Glad I could help! :)